# basic_auth not working anymore after moving from JIRA to JIRA DataCenter, SSLError 443 error

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, jira

I was using JIRA API for Python up until now to connect to JIRA, like so:

```
from jira import JIRA
options = {'server': 'http://it.company.com/'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('user', 'token'), max_retries=1)
```

However, since we moved from JIRA to JIRA DataCenter yesterday, this script doesn't work anymore. I get the following error message:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='it.company.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Why is this occurring? What changed in the authentication from JIRA to Jira DataCenter?

Answer (score 0):

Today it works again. I'm not sure what the cause of the error was.